# refresh android screen based on button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view

I am making a simple Reversi game for Android, and the problem I am having is that when the player makes a move, there is no delay between the player and the AI. So when the player makes a move, the next thing that the player will see is the AI's move. What I want is the player to make a move, the correct tiles are flipped, the AI makes a move, the correct tiles are flipped, repeat. I think what the issue is is that I am only using one Activity. Can this be achieved using one Activity using postInvalidate() or refreshDrawableState(), or do I need to have another (or multiple) activities?

Comment: Have you tried using view.postDelayed() to make the AI move?

Comment: You just need to implement a pause. There are many ways. You don't need extra activities just to have your program run at a slower pace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// After user completes a turn, use a handler to delay the AI's move :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        AIsMove();
      }
    }, 2000);
```